# How to add hardware acceleration for SVG Animation in browser?

Tags: svg, html5-canvas, svg-animate

I am trying to add SVG animations in my HTML5 Canvas Game.
Are SVG Animations Hardware Accelerated?
What are the ways we ca make SVG animations faster in browser?

Answer (score 3):

**The SVG Animations are GPU accelerated in latest versions of Chrome**. More details can be found on link [Chrome: Updates in hardware-accelerated animation capabilities](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/hardware-accelerated-animations/)

**Summary**: Chromium is updating its hardware-acceleration capabilities automatically for SVG animations, percentage-based transformations, and soon, background-color and clip-path animations.

**Enabling hardware-accelerated animations**

Hardware-accelerated animations are composited as layers and help developers achieve buttery-smooth 60 FPS (frames-per-second) animations to improve visual rendering performance. There are currently a few ways to specify and enable hardware-accelerated animations and transitions on the web:

- Use CSS transform functions or transition the opacity or filter
  values
- Add the will-change property to your element.
- Create an animated canvas drawing via OffscreenCanvas Create a
  WebGL 3D drawing

**For hardware acceleration details**, type below url in Chrome browser.

- `chrome://gpu`
- The browser will show something like below.

[image: Hardware Acceleration in Browser Info]